# How can I be able to perform a filter on a nested List within another java list

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream, dto, projection

Disclaimer: I am really new to Java and i am trying to transform this json in springboot using streams to obtain an output as indicated below. But all my trials are failing, what am i doing wrong with this.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "year": 2020,
        "description": "Two thousand twenty",
        "brands": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Tesla",
                "description": "This is a car provider from USA",
                "countryId": 16,
                "brandNo": "TE001",
                "categoryId": 23
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Toyota",
                "description": "This is a car provider from Japan",
                "countryId": 16,
                "brandNo": "TE003",
                "categoryId": 23
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "year": 2022,
        "description": "Two thousand twenty",
        "brands": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Tesla",
                "description": "This is a car provider from USA",
                "countryId": 16,
                "brandNo": "TE001",
                "categoryId": 23
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Toyota",
                "description": "This is a car provider from Japan",
                "countryId": 16,
                "brandNo": "TE003",
                "categoryId": 23
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The output i am look to get is based on if the user passes a name for the brand that `"Toyota"` then the output should be.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "year": 2020,
        "description": "Two thousand twenty",
        "brands": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Toyota",
                "description": "This is a car provider from Japan",
                "countryId": 16,
                "brandNo": "TE003",
                "categoryId": 23
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "year": 2022,
        "description": "Two thousand twenty",
        "brands": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Toyota",
                "description": "This is a car provider from Japan",
                "countryId": 16,
                "brandNo": "TE003",
                "categoryId": 23
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My current code snippet I am using looks like the one below. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
  List<YearBrandDTO> years = yearRepository.findAll().stream()
                    .map(year -> year.getBrands().stream()
                            .filter(brand -> brand.getName().equals("Toyota")))
                    .map(year -> modelMapper.map(year, YearBrandDTO.class))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And my DTO looks like this

```
@Data
public class YearBrandDTO {
        private Long id;
        private Integer year;
        private String description;
        private Object brands;
}
```

But the output i get is null values

```
   [
        {
            "id": null,
            "year": null,
            "description": null,
            "brands": null
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to map the result of filtering brands directly to the `YearBrandDTO`. But you should filter the brands first and then create a new `YearBrandDTO` object.

Like this:

```
List<YearBrandDTO> years = yearRepository.findAll().stream()
    .map(year -> {
        List<Brand> filteredBrands = year.getBrands().stream()
            .filter(brand -> brand.getName().equals("Toyota"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        YearBrandDTO yearBrandDTO = modelMapper.map(year, YearBrandDTO.class);
        yearBrandDTO.setBrands(filteredBrands);
        return yearBrandDTO;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This way you should be able to get the desired output. Just update your `YearBrandDTO` class to have a `List<BrandDTO>` instead of an Object for the brand's field.

```
@Data
public class YearBrandDTO {
    private Long id;
    private Integer year;
    private String description;
    private List<BrandDTO> brands;
}
```

In your case, I would need to create a `BrandDTO` class similar to your `YearBrandDTO` class to **map** the brand fields.

Comment: Thank you @devblack.exe , I have implemented what you shared though I faced another issue. It complained at this line `yearBrandDTO.setBrands(finalBrands);` that it expected data of type `List<BrandDTO>` yet provide `List<BrandEntity>`, then I did another stream of the `List<BrandDTO> finalBrands = filteredBrands.stream().map(brand -> modelMapper.map(brand, BrandDTO.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());` to get a List<BrandDTO>` but now my response returns `[{"id": 1, "year": 2020, "description": "Two thousand twenty", "brands": []}]`, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you @devblack.exe, I have managed to fix the issue, with the previous comment of converting the BrandEntity into BrandDTO was working well, the challenge was now around the way I was sending in my `RequestParam`, it was wrapped around quotes which Java was considering a totally different string. After removing the quotes I managed to get the data I wanted.